# How to prevent a combo box from droppping down in HTML?

Tags: php, html, forms

The user sees a web form with a bunch of controls. One of them is a combo box (drop down list) with several options.

He selects one and hits the submit button. My PHP form action validates the input & shows the submission as a read-only version of the input form for confirmation.

I would like to prevent the combobox from dropping down, using only HTML generated by PHP.

Can I?

---

Edit:  I need to display it as it was in the original form (WYSIWYG), so can't just use plain text

Comment: What's the point of having a confirmation screen if the user can't change anything?

Comment: Combo box != drop down list. Combo boxes are a *combination* of a drop down list and a text entry field, i.e. text entry fields that also have pre-defined values to choose from. These don't exist in the HTML spec. `</nitpick>`

Comment: If it's just for confirmation, why do you need a drop-down in the first place? Can't you just display it as plain text?

Comment: "What's the point of having a confirmation screen if the user can't change anything? "  So he knows that his input was valid and can see what it was.

Comment: "If it's just for confirmation, why do you need a drop-down in the first place? Can't you just display it as plain text?"

I need to display it as it was in the original form (WYSIWYG), so can't just use plain text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

`select#some-id { color: black; }`

`<select id='some-id' disabled='disabled'><option value='some-value'>Text to Show</option></select>`

The CSS is to prevent the "grayed out" behaviour of a disabled form element. The little tick next to the text field will still be grayed out, which intuitively suggests that drop-down is not available.

Comment: "which intuitively suggests that drop-down is not available" - despite the fact that it still is :-)   Thanks, though (+1). I might end up using this.

Comment: Hey mawg. If disabled=disabled attribute is included, the drop-down is indeed unavailable. At least, that is the case in Firefox. I didn't cross-test, tbqh.

Comment: The styling of the color doesn't work in IE8, but it is indeed disabled.

Comment: And actually, you can just use 
<select id='some-id' disabled><option value='some-value'>Text to Show</option></select>
and it still works.

Comment: @Zerofiz, you can definitely do that in any smart browser and plenty of stupid ones, to boot. But that breaks XHTML1 parsing if that is a design goal :)

Comment: I guess what I'm finding out is that there just isn't a cross-browser compatible way to have your cake and eat it, too. Hmm.